# Dynamically load an abstract class and implementation from separate JARs

Tags: java

I have an java app which loads several plugins (.jar files) from FS dynamically. For each plugin I use such code:

```
URLClassLoader cl = URLClassLoader.newInstance( new URL[] { jarFile } );
Class<?> loadedClass = cl.loadClass( PluginEntry );
BasePlugin plugin = (basePlugin)loadedClass.newInstance();
```

And it's all ok. I have 2 plugins which inherit the same class, here is a structure:
    interface BasePlugin -> app.jar
    abstract class BaseA implements BasePlugin -> baseA.jar
    class B extends BaseA -> pluginB.jar
    class C extends BaseA -> pluginC.jar

But I need to put baseA package to both pluginB.jar and pluginC.jar and it's the problem. What I want to do is to remove BaseA.jar from pluginB/C packages and to load BaseA.jar dynamically from FS before loading pluginB and pluginC.
I tried to do this

```
URLClassLoader cl = URLClassLoader.newInstance( new URL[] { baseAjarFile } );
Class<?> loadedClass = cl.loadClass( PluginEntry );
```

but i cannot do anything with that loadedClass. And when App is loading pluginB/C it fails with java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError exception.
So how can I load this common abstract base class and make it available for pluginB/C?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
URLClassLoader.newInstance( new URL[] { baseAjarFile }, cl);
```